# SQL Choose rows based on infant ID and whether the infant's mother ID is in the row or not

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm very new to SQL and this is only my second post on stackoverflow. I'm trying to follow the rules but please excuse my n00bness. Thanks in advance for your time and help. I'm using MS Access.

I'm studying infant social development and mother-infant interactions. To make this easier to understand, I simplified all of the following:

I have 2 tables: biography and interactions. Biography consists of the infant identity code, date of birth of the infant, and the infant's mother. Interactions consists of data collected while observing the infants and their mothers (as well as peers). I observe an infant for a set amount of time and record their behavior at each timestamp. If the behavior involves a partner (I'm specifically interested in play behavior) I include the identity of the partner.

What I would like to do is take out all the "play" rows in which the mother is the only play partner (because I'm interested in when the infant plays with peers rather than the mother). I want to include rows in which the infant is playing with the mother AND a peer (because this counts as playing with a peer). I think this entails relating the two tables using the mom column of each infant's id. I think, in English, this could be described as: Exclude play rows where mom is the only play partner. It's important to note that who the mother is obviously depends on who the infant being observed is.

As you can see below, sometimes there are multiple play partners. Again, I do want to include rows such as the last few, where cc is playing with it's mother AND aa. The partner id's are usually separated by a space, but sometimes there are typos and there is no space or more than one space. There may even be some commas. But the ID codes are consistent and will always be there typed correctly. The dataset includes tens of thousands of lines so I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to complete this task. The tables are visualized below:

biography

```
id   |    dob     |   mom
-------------------------
aa     2015-01-01     mom_a
bb     2016-01-01     mom_b
cc     2017-01-01     mom_c
```

interactions

```
id    |    behavior  |  partner   |    time
---------------------------------------------
aa         play         mom_a          12:00
aa         rest                        12:05
aa         play         bb             12:10
aa         play         bb             12:15
aa         rest                        12:20
bb         rest                        13:00
bb         rest                        13:05
bb         play         mom_b          13:10
bb         play         cc             13:15
bb         rest                        13:20
cc         rest                        14:00
cc         play         aa bb          14:05
cc         play         mom_c aa bb    14:10
cc         play         mom_c aa       14:15
cc         play         mom_c aa       14:20
cc         play         mom_c aa       14:25
```

Comment: You need to introduce a new table with Id, time and partner...gotta normalize the structure...you don't want multiple partners in the same row

Comment: So Partner field is just a string, and inconsistent structure? Agree you really should normalize data.

Answer (score 0):

I think, below query may work, I haven't tried it yet.

```
select * from biography bio
  inner join interactions itr
    on bio.id = itr.id
  where itr.partner not like bio.mom
```

Please note, if your interactions table is going to have large amount of data then having a "not like" clause will degrade performance. Also, you may wish to normalize the interaction table so that you do not need to keep all the partners in same row.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your input. It seems clear that I should normalize the structure. Do you suggest that I break partners up into separate columns, like partner 1, partner 2, partner 3, etc.?

Comment: No. You should register each partner in a separate record.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should normalize your data structure. But the following should work with what you have:

```
SELECT *
FROM interactions i
WHERE behavior = 'play'
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM biography b
 WHERE i.partner = b.mom
 AND i.id = b.id)
```

So take the rows in interactions where:

1. Behavior = play
2. Partner does not have an exact match in biography.mom for the same id

Comment: Thanks that works really well for now! If you have the time, would you explain to me where the number 1 comes from?

Comment: Also, I tried to check but can't quite confirm-what I need is for records where the mother is the only play partner to be excluded IF the mother is the mother of the infant who is the one being observed at that given time. So if the infant being observed was aa, and the play partner was just mom_a, then yes, I would want that excluded. But if the infant being observed was bb, and the play partner was only mom_a, then I would want to include that, because it is not the mother of the infant being observed. The infant being observed at any given time is indicated by id in the interaction table.

Comment: I hope that makes sense, and thank you again for your help.

Comment: The 1 is just a convention. That could be 5 or 10 or * or 'Hello World'. The EXISTS clause just checks that something is being returned by the query.